# example.com/wp-login.php redirects me to example.com/example.com/wp-admin

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a local website on my computer, and now I uploaded all the files to another host via SSH.

I have two problems:

1. When I connect to the **example.com/wp-login.php** page, it redirects me to **example.com/example.com/wp-admin**.
2. On example.com, when I touch to Login button, it redirects me to a page that says, "**The requested URL /login/ was not found on this server.**"

The first time, I had a **wp-loging.php** page without style, but I fixed it.

Can you please help me?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your question to include your code. See [guidelines for asking an effective question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

In the database please make sure the siteurl in wp_options table is correct.
Also, make sure that the config file doesnt have `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL` defined incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

**If** http:// or Https:// missing in front of **example.com/wp-login.php** then it will redirect to **example.com/** + **example.com/wp-login.php**

**I**f url start with no http ftp ... then browser think its a **sub-page** of this host.

so if http missing on **example.com/wp-login.php** then add http:// **Or** you can remove **example.com** from ***example.com/wp-login.php*** and only use **/wp-login.php**